# cascading dropdown shows dictionary/array

Tags: javascript

For my project i need a cascading dropdown. I used the example from here https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/65Q9L/

great example and it worked,... half i keep getting my data as sort af an array

```
[(&amp;#39;TEST HEALTCARE&amp;#39;,), (&amp;#39;TEST HEALTCARE2&amp;#39;,), (&amp;#39;Test healtcare&amp;#39;,)]
```

same goes for the second and third select option.

I'm using flask with jinja and the data comes from an sqlite database

any idea on how i can get a list with the values instead of the array ?

thx !!

UPDATE :

I found a way to return a JSON type list trough this snippet

```
 var keyValueData = {{ keyValueProjects|tojson }}
         //console.log(keyValueData);

    var result = JSON.parse(keyValueData);
    var healthcare = {};
```

but the result is I get a error

```
VM1384:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

this is my output:

```
var keyValueData = {"TEST ENTERPRISE": ["SubEnterprise 1"], "test Enterprise": ["subEnterprise"]}
         //console.log(keyValueData);

    var result = JSON.parse(keyValueData);
    var healthcare = [];
```

From what I understand I think it has to do with the "{" at the beginning of the JSON. any idea on how i can get rid of this. Or do I miss something.

thxx!

Comment: How to `"Fix"` what ?

Comment: I rephrased my question :any idea on how i can get a list with the values instead of the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to parse the object as it is already parsed.

simply use the

> keyValueData object.

like below

```
var keyValueData = {{ keyValueProjects|tojson }}     
    var result = *keyValueData* 
    var healthcare = {};
```